# How to push client-to-client notifications in Angular/Ionic using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I need to make client-client push notifications (NOT server-to-client), I want to trigger a notification when a user sends a message to another.

Is that possible? How I can do that based on this structure in the firebase real-time database:?

Firebase Structure Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebase cloud functions for that. You can add a cloud function that will trigger when you add a message in the messages collection. And then send the notification.

You can see the cloud firestore triggers here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Here is an example cloud function for a notification when a user subscribes:

```
exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore
.document('subscribers/{subscriptionId}')
.onCreate(async event => {

const data = event.after.data();

const userId = data.userId
const subscriber = data.subscriberId

// Notification content
const payload = {
  notification: {
      title: 'New Subscriber',
      body: `${subscriber} is following your content!`,
      icon: '[insert icon url]'
  }
}

// ref to the device collection for the user
const db = admin.firestore()
const devicesRef = db.collection('devices').where('userId', '==', userId)


// get the user's tokens and send notifications
const devices = await devicesRef.get();

const tokens = [];

// send a notification to each device token
devices.forEach(result => {
  const token = result.data().token;

  tokens.push( token )
})

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)

});
```

Comment: Actually, I've already written a cloud function that triggers when you add a message in the messages collection(https://i.imgur.com/4KlKMp3.png). But in your URL I didn't find a way to push notifications between users after adding a message to messages collection.

Comment: Hi, In order to send notification. You will use firebase.messaging() You can see the documentation here [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message)

Comment: I added an example cloud function for sending notifications to a subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have an actual notification pop up or can you handle this within your application?

If you can handle it within your application, then you can use the firebase `addChildEventListener` to handle updates to the user message collection you are watching.  In the event handler you will have a `result.type` that will tell you when `ChildAdded` event happened and your application then can show a notification to the user.

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: THX. No, I need a real notification like Whatsapp or FB Messenger.